# Result set takes long to process big data from Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, resultset

In an Oracle db, I have a query `select * from tablehistory`

1. The query can run fast and returns 500,000 records. That's not an issue.
2. The challenge is the result set takes a long long time to loop over.
3. How do I solve that result set taking a long time to loop over?
4. The result set data, I plan to save it into a hash map/do processing.
5. Below code, start 1, 2, 3 print fast, start 4 takes long time to print; it's slow

How do I speed up my code?

```
String mayquery="select * from tablehistory";   
try {
        System.out.println("# start 0");
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(mayquery);
        System.out.println("# start 1");
        ResultSet resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        System.out.println("# start 2");
        int count =0;
        System.out.println("# start 3");
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            System.out.println("start 4 count:"+count);
            count++;
        }
        System.out.println("# end a");
        System.out.println("count:"+count);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        
    }
```

Comment: if tablehistory is just a table (not a view), then the problem is not with oracle, but in your network: it may take a very long time to get the data  to you. Here I suppose you're connecting to the db over network. And when you say 'the query can run fast', and it returns 500k rows, what do you mean by fast? did you try the query soemwhere and let it get back the 500K rows and it was fast?

Comment: Ever hear the phrase 'row by row = slow by slow' ?  Of course 'looping over the rows' is going to take more time. You are stopping at each row and doing work with that row.  A simple SELECT gathers all of the rows as a set and  returns them - again, as a set - to the client and the client simply writes them to the output device.

Comment: You say that "start 4 takes a long time to print" but "start 4" should be printed 500,000 times.  Are you saying it takes a long time for the first "start 4" to print?  Or the 500,000th?  What does "long time" mean to you?  Fetching half a million rows from the database to a client application is seldom an ideal way to architect a process.  But if you're going to do that, you'd almost certainly want to set `setFetchSize` to a larger value.  Generally somewhere in the 100 - 1000 range but you can test what works best in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try setting resultSet.setFetchSize(int) this to a higher value. By default, it is set as 10. This parameter controls number of network calls from server to DB and can increase performance when used optimally.
2. Check for network latency.
3. System.out.println() is a heavy operation. Rather than printing this each time, try printing a line for an interval.